# EF mapping question

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, ef-code-first

Lets say I have the following classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get;set;}
    public string Firstname { get;set;}
    public Interests Interests { get;set;}
}
public class Interests
{
    public IList<Team> FavoriteTeams { get;set;}
    public IList<Food> FavoriteFoods { get;set;}
}
public class Team{
    public int TeamId { get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}
    public string Name { get;;set;}
}
public class Food{
    public int FoodId { get;set;}
    public string FoodName { get;set;}
}
```

At the database level I would like to have the following tables:

Users
Teams
Foods
UserTeams
UserFoods

Basically I would like to have the Interests property of the user entity but not have a seperate table for it.

I am using EF 4.1 code first POCO classes. I know the easiest thing to do is put the Teams and Food collection as a property on the User, which is ok, but from the object model point of view I would like it be be its own property.  Any idea of how I would acheive this type of mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say: The mapping you are looking for is not possible, because:

If you don't want the class `Interests` to be mapped to a table, it must not be an entity and the `Interests` property in your `User` class must not be a navigation property. To avoid that EF interprets the `Interests` property as a navigation property, you would only have two options:

- Mark it as `NotMapped` -> Does not help because you would lose the relationship from `User` to `Team` and `Food` completely
- Mark the `Interests` class as `ComplexType` -> Not possible in your example because complex types are [not allowed to contain navigation properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx).

That's just from my level of understanding. It's not unlikely that I overlooked another option.

Comment: It's too bad that EF doesn't support navigation properties on complex types, something competing frameworks have supported since the beginning of time. I wish I could say I'm surprised...